# Please help to remove specific lines from text

Tags: linux, sed

I need to remove :

```
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  { 
     }
```

from text file.
Rules:
there should be no word between {} 
lalala could be any word.

Text before:

```
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  { 
        ha hah haha
     }
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  { 

     }
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  { 
            lal lal lal
     }
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  { 
     }
```

Text After:

```
  guide_change_names \
      -design { lalala } \
      { 
            ha hah haha
         }

    guide_change_names \
      -design { lalala } \
      { 
                lal lal lal
         }
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking to remove. Please, provide an example of text before and after the remove operation.

Comment: Six questions with zero votes and zero accepted answers. Are you a hit & runner?

Comment: I didnt know that I need to vote and accept questions. from now I will do it.

Comment: @IgorBoguslavetz: Those are good news. And also it will help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **GNU** `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="guide_change_names[^{]*{[^}]*}[^{]*{[ \n]*}[ \n]*" } 1' file
```

Here idea is to set Record Separator (RS) as the pattern to be removed.

Output:

```
guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  {
        ha hah haha
     }

guide_change_names \
  -design { lalala } \
  {
            lal lal lal
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk). Set the record separator `RS` to `guide_change_names...}..}` and overwrite it to `""` if only spaces are contained between the second pair of curly braces

```
awk --re-interval -v RS='guide_change_names([^}]+[}]){2}\\n' \
    'RT ~ /[{][[:space:]]+[}]\n$/{RT=""};{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file.txt
```